# PrettyPhoto scroll issue

Tags: fusioncharts, prettyphoto

I cannot understand why prettyphoto it's not showing the chart if the page has the scroll bar active.

Please check at these two pages, they have exactly the same code with the exception that the second one has more paragraphs and doesn't fit in one screen.
http://education.miami.edu/sp/itworks.html
http://education.miami.edu/sp/itdoesntwork.html

I would really appreciate your help!
Thanks,

Daniele

Comment: you know this is a coding platform?

Comment: yes, why? Isn't my question about a coding issue? I'm not asking for the recipe of the cheesecake :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you give more information. When I open both the pages in Chrome, it is working fine for me.

Also, please note that FusionCharts has stopped supporting the flash version of charts [the charts in your example pages uses Flash version of charts]. You can use the javascript version of their charts.